Python Django Hangs at Runserver (solved). No logs available
This is a different question, as the previous query pertains to migrating his app to an ubuntu box and not able to run his django app..
In my case, this is running in a local macos system with it's database using Neon postgres online. The difference is that this was previously OK using the same system without any migrations performed...
Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Is there a way to show some logs/errors while runserver is being executed (hanged)?
When running:
python manage.py runserver
It hangs...
(venv-saas) jdv@jdv-MBP src % python manage.py runserver 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).


This problem has now been solved.. The solution to the problem entailed two actions: 1. The cloud database was archived because it was idle for the past few days. We have to bring it back to production. 2. There were firewall settings that were permitted in order for the app to access the database. Hope this helps for others who experience the same problem...
